# is the Security Token in Salescloud affecting our connection with Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

For security reasons, we have to reset our security token following this article:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_security_token.htm&type=5

Would this affect our connection with Marketing Cloud or any other integration?

Thanks

Comment: For any other integration, were you using `Security Token`? I believe no one uses `Security Token` in a real world scenario for integrations.

Answer (score 0):

Any integration that is authenticated using OAuth will be unaffected by a reset of the security token.

Any integration that is authenticated via a username and password stored by the remote system may be affected, depending on your specific security configuration and whether or not the remote system is located inside your trusted networks.

While you can update any stored credentials to utilize your new security token, the best fix for such integrations is to convert them to us OAuth, because it is resilient to such changes and does not require storing credentials. OAuth is a more secure solution.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed it is not really clear in your answer if specifically Marketing Cloud connector would be affected or not. Can you please clarify? Thanks!

Comment: I do not know the answer to that specific question because I am not a Marketing Cloud expert. Other community members may be able to illuminate how Marketing Cloud authenticates.